# Escaping single and double quotes in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

my string `${field.value}` has values

```
'<table id="tblUserList">            
        <tbody>                 
        <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">some test' and "xyz"</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody
        </table>'
```

What i have tried is

```
escapestring = '${field.value}'

escapestring.replace("'", "\'");

document.getElementById("tblUserList").innerHTML  = escapestring ;
```

Error,it is not working

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

I want to escape single quote and double quote in the `some test' and "xyz"`

I am trying to make the `string safe for inserting into HTML table.`

**Update:** values are coming from server, i can't skip the HTML elements in string

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/e3jehrc5/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will have to assign something back `escapestring = escapestring.replace("'", "\'");`

Comment: Provide a real [MCVE]. You say you are fetching values using `innerHTML`, but your code example attempts to use a hard coded string literal … and has several errors in it that prevents the code from compiling. You also need to describe what you want to achieve, "escaping" only makes sense with a context. Escaping for what? Are you trying to make the string safe for inserting into SQL? Are you trying to make it safe for inserting into JSON? Something else?

Comment: Pull the brakes… You're "fetching from `innerHTML`", so I'm assuming you have something like `string = element.innerHTML`. In that scenario there's nothing to escape. You only need to escape string literals if you literally write HTML in your Javascript code, but that's somewhat contrary to "fetching from `innerHTML`", and you'd need to do that in your literal string and not after the fact with `replace`…

Comment: @deceze I have updated my qusetion

Comment: "I am trying to make the string safe for inserting into table" — What sort of table? An HTML table? A table in a relational database? How are you trying to insert it? Provide a real [MCVE].

Comment: "`string safe for inserting into HTML table`" is a vague description. Show us a real [MCVE]. (And don't use the code markup for things that aren't code).

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa this might help [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/e3jehrc5/)

Comment: You need to replace this from server side if you place this here in js code it will surely give error.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines here…

> ```
> escapestring = '${field.value}'
> ```

I'm guessing some server-side templating language is filling in the value of `${field.value}` here. First: you should not dynamically generate Javascript on the fly, it would be a much better idea to fetch this HTML snippet via AJAX or such.

Having said this, since your server is dynamically generating Javascript source code here, it needs to take care to produce **syntactically valid code**. Right now you're naïvely pasting a string into another string, without regards to the syntactic requirements of what you're producing. You cannot fix this in Javascript, since the Javascript itself is already invalid. Your templating language needs to properly encode the string to be valid Javascript. How to do that exactly depends on your templating system; here's a PHP example:

```
var html = <?= json_encode($field->value); ?>;
```

JSON encoding here produces valid Javascript literals, which is all you're looking for here.

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
var escapestring ='<table id="tblUserList"><tbody><tr><td style="padding: 10px;">some test'+"'"+' and "xyz"</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```